# What i do Amazon Policy s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Error
Policy has invalid resource

---

```
{
   "Version":"2008-10-17",
   "Id":"ZencoderBucketPolicy",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"Stmt1295042087538",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::395540211253:root"
         },
         "Action":[
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::www.salammee.com/*"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"Stmt1295042087538",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::395540211253:root"
         },
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::www.salammee. com"
      }
   ]
}


{
   "Id":"Policy1600123708938",
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"Stmt1600123692406",
         "Action":"s3:*",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::www.salammee.com/*",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":[
               "amermagd"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You have a space character in `arn:aws:s3:::www.salammee. com`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you very much, really, that is why you are so wonderful

Comment: How do I fix a video display....mutasah wakadha fidyu lakunah la yaemal
The video is uploading, but upon presentation, I find a black page with a black paper cut out ... it does not work final and I tried it on such a correct and such video but it does not work